# How to go from a 3 element tuple to 2 element tuple python

Tags: python-2.7, tuples

Let say i have 3 list that I zip:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [5,4,3]
c = [4,5,2]

d = zip(a,b,c)
```

How would I unzip d to a list of tuples of 2 element

I can

```
a,b,c = zip(*d)
zip(a,b)
```

Is there a better way? I am currently doing this to sort the list of tuples then remove the largest last value(c) but return a list of tuple of 2 element. Third tuple acts like a key for removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do what you describe would just be with slices and a list comprehension.  For example:

```
>>> d
[(1, 5, 4), (2, 4, 5), (3, 3, 2)]
>>> [x[:2] for x in d]
[(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: I see that makes sense. Thank you.